# Change private static final field using Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, static, private, final

I have a class with a `private static final` field that, unfortunately, I need to change it at run-time.

Using reflection I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final boolean field`

Is there any way to change the value?

```
Field hack = WarpTransform2D.class.getDeclaredField("USE_HACK");
hack.setAccessible(true);
hack.set(null, true);
```

Comment: Such a bad idea.  I'd try to get the source and recompile (or even decompile/recompile) instead.

Comment: System.out is a public static final field, but it can be changed too.

Comment: @irreputable `System.out/in/err` are so "special" that the Java Memory Model has to make special mention of them. They are not examples which should be followed.

Comment: well my point ws to find a hack in the between to have my app working until the lib responsible make the change at the next release so i don't need to hack anymore...

Comment: @Bill K from ten years ago:  It would be GREAT to recompile it but it's on a deployed system and I just need to patch it until we can update the deployed app!

Comment: For Java 17 [Get declared fields of java.lang.reflect.Fields in jdk12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71465198/432903)

Answer (score 1021, accepted):

Assuming no `SecurityManager` is preventing you from doing this, you can use `setAccessible` to get around `private` and resetting the modifier to get rid of `final`, and actually modify a `private static final` field.

Here's an example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class EverythingIsTrue {
   static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
      field.setAccessible(true);

      Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

      field.set(null, newValue);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {      
      setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getField("FALSE"), true);

      System.out.format("Everything is %s", false); // "Everything is true"
   }
}
```

Assuming no `SecurityException` is thrown, the above code prints `"Everything is true"`.

What's actually done here is as follows:

- The primitive `boolean` values `true` and `false` in `main` are autoboxed to reference type `Boolean` "constants" `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`
- Reflection is used to change the [`public static final Boolean.FALSE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE) to refer to the `Boolean` referred to by `Boolean.TRUE`
- As a result, subsequently whenever a `false` is autoboxed to `Boolean.FALSE`, it refers to the same `Boolean` as the one refered to by `Boolean.TRUE`
- Everything that was `"false"` now is `"true"`

#### Related questions

- [Using reflection to change `static final File.separatorChar` for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474017/using-reflection-to-change-static-final-file-separatorchar-for-unit-testing/2474242#2474242)
- [How to limit setAccessible to only “legitimate” uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses)

  - Has examples of messing with `Integer`'s cache, mutating a `String`, etc

---

#### Caveats

Extreme care should be taken whenever you do something like this. It may not work because a `SecurityManager` may be present, but even if it doesn't, depending on usage pattern, it may or may not work.

> [JLS 17.5.3 Subsequent Modification of Final Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5.3)
>
> In some cases, such as deserialization, the system will need to change the `final` fields of an object after construction. `final` fields can be changed via reflection and other implementation dependent means. The only pattern in which this has reasonable semantics is one in which an object is constructed and then the `final` fields of the object are updated. The object should not be made visible to other threads, nor should the `final` fields be read, until all updates to the `final` fields of the object are complete. Freezes of a `final` field occur both at the end of the constructor in which the `final` field is set, and immediately after each modification of a `final` field via reflection or other special mechanism.
>
> Even then, there are a number of complications. If a `final` field is initialized to a compile-time constant in the field declaration, changes to the `final` field may not be observed, since uses of that `final` field are replaced at compile time with the compile-time constant.
>
> Another problem is that the specification allows aggressive optimization of `final` fields. Within a thread, it is permissible to reorder reads of a `final` field with those modifications of a final field that do not take place in the constructor.

#### See also

- [JLS 15.28 Constant Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

  - It's unlikely that this technique works with a primitive `private static final boolean`, because it's inlineable as a compile-time constant and thus the "new" value may not be observable

---

#### Appendix: On the bitwise manipulation

Essentially,

```
field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL
```

turns off the bit corresponding to `Modifier.FINAL` from `field.getModifiers()`. `&` is the bitwise-and, and `~` is the bitwise-complement.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations)

---

#### Remember Constant Expressions

Still not being able to solve this?, have fallen onto depression like I did for it? Does your code looks like this?

```
public class A {
    private final String myVar = "Some Value";
}
```

Reading the comments on this answer, specially the one by @Pshemo, it reminded me that [Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) are handled different so it will be **impossible** to modify it. Hence you will need to change your code to look like this:

```
public class A {
    private final String myVar;

    private A() {
        myVar = "Some Value";
    }
}
```

*if you are not the owner of the class... I feel you!*

For more details about why this behavior [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506329/java-final-field-compile-time-constant-expression)?

Comment: When I saw this: `System.out.format("Everything is %s", false); // "Everything is true"` I thought you were screwing with us, then I read the rest of your code, but it brings up a readability question, some things your just accept as true (or in this case, false).

Comment: @thecoop, @HalfBrian: there is no doubt that this is _EXTREMELY EVIL_, but this example was chosen by design. My answer only shows how, in some circumstances, this is possible. The most disgusting example that I can think of is deliberate chosen with the hope that perhaps people would be instantly disgusted by instead of falling in love with the technique.

Comment: Yo, dawg.  I heard you like reflection, so I reflected on field so you can reflect while you reflect.

Comment: I want to use this for testing by replacing a singleton with a mock object without compromising the singleton in production code.

Comment: Note that Boolean.FALSE is **not** private.Does this really work with "private final static" members?

Comment: @mgaert it does, but you have to use `getDeclaredField()` instead of `getField()` for target class

Comment: +1. For those who will try to change something like `final String myConstant = "x";` and will fail: remember that compile time constants will be inlined by compiler so when you will write code like `System.out.println(myConstant);` it will be compiled as `System.out.println("x");` because compiler knows value of constant at compile time. To get rid of this problem you need to initialize your constants at runtime like `final String myConstant = new String("x");`. Also in case of primitives like `final int myField = 11` use `final int myField = new Integer(11);` or `final Integer myField = 11;`

Comment: Note that you can check the `SecurityManager` beforehand to see if you're allowed to do this: `final SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager(); if (sm != null) { sm.checkPermission(new java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")); }`

Comment: Appears it does not work with `static final` fields of primitive types even if they are initialized with something that is _not_ compile time constant (property access in my case).

Comment: I tried to use your code one Android, but modifiers said NoSuchField..
Android uses Java 1.7 I believe.

Comment: Never mind, looking at the Android source, I found out, that the "modifiers" field is "accessFlags" on Android.

Comment: Why this business with modifying bitmasks?.setAccessible(true) turns of all language checks anyways right?

Comment: What is `"modifiers"`? Does it some kind of system field that is generated automatically by compiler? How this one is  related to `field` method parameter (value of which we are trying to change)?

Comment: @ieXcept `modifiers` is a private member of the `Field` class.  It is set to the appropriate bit pattern for the modifiers of the field represented by that particular `field` instance.

Comment: Great for having a program changing its own environment (or, at least, the return value of System.getenv()).  Why the environment is immutable is a question I am not wise enough to know the answer to.

Comment: Note that JLS §17.5.3 is referring to non-`static` `final` fields. Subsequent modification of `static` `final` fields is not foreseen at all and hence, entirely off specification. Anything can happen, including no effect at all or a complete crash of the JVM…

Comment: Another caveat is that you can't read the Field before removing the modifier or it gets cached: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49102935/1553851

Comment: Doesnt make sense why u got 2 fields

Comment: In Java 12 this is no longer allowed. See bug 8210496
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8210496
https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk12u/rev/f55a4bc91ef4

Comment: Does this works for the final static field of a static class ? I try but looks like the field of the static class was not changed as expected.

Comment: Evil and working, thank you >:-D Unfortunately does not work on Java 13.

Comment: This worked for setting a `static final` logger to a mocked logger in a test. Thank you!

Comment: Mind (again) that “JLS 17.5.3 Subsequent Modification of Final Fields” applies to *instance fields* only. It describes the problems which may happen when you “change the final fields of an object after construction” whereas changing a `static final` field after the class initialization is not even foreseen by the specification. That’s why for a non-static `final` field a simple `setAccessible(true)` is enough to change it whereas changing a `static final` field requires deeper hacks which the JDK developers try to disable. Even if you find another work-around, it’ll break the next version.

Comment: As mentioned in Ans"Final field is initialized to a compile-time constant in the field declaration, changes to the final field may not be observed" -any way to work on this when the fields is inbuilt @Holger

Comment: @swpalmer Yep, not working in Java 12 anymore, check [this answer for the new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043252/2979435) trick

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers

Comment: I am using this solution in my testing and I want to tear down the changes done to the variable. How can I revert (put back final modifier back) setFinalStatic method changes once the testing is done ?

Comment: So if I wanted to make the field final again, would I just omit the tilde `~`?

Comment: I wonder how this could work on JDK 17. I think `modifiers` is not accessible anymore.

Comment: not working on 17

Comment: It doesn't work with java 17 :)

Answer (score 69):

If the value assigned to a `static final boolean` field is known at compile-time, it is a *constant.* Fields of primitive or 
`String` type can be compile-time constants. A constant will be inlined in any code that references the field. Since the field is not actually read at runtime, changing it then will have no effect.

The [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9) says this:

> If a field is a constant variable
>   (§4.12.4), then deleting the keyword
>   final or changing its value will not
>   break compatibility with pre-existing
>   binaries by causing them not to run,
>   but **they will not see any new value
>   for the usage of the field unless they
>   are recompiled.** This is true even if
>   the usage itself is not a compile-time
>   constant expression (§15.28)

Here's an example:

```
class Flag {
  static final boolean FLAG = true;
}

class Checker {
  public static void main(String... argv) {
    System.out.println(Flag.FLAG);
  }
}
```

If you decompile `Checker`, you'll see that instead of referencing `Flag.FLAG`, the code simply pushes a value of 1 (`true`) onto the stack (instruction #3).

```
0:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3:   iconst_1
4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
7:   return
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but then I remembered Java compiled at runtime, if you were to reset the bit it would simply recompile with it as a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: @Bill K - No, this doesn't refer to JIT compilation. The dependent class files will actually contain the inlined values, and no reference to the independent class. It's a pretty simple experiment to test; I will add an example.

Comment: How does this jive with @polygenelubricants 's answer where he redefines Boolean.false?--but you are correct, I've seen this behavior when things didn't recompile correctly.

Comment: @Bill K - in polygenlubricants' answer, the field is not a compile time constant. It's `public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false)` not `public static final boolean FALSE = false`

Answer (score 20):

A little curiosity from the Java Language Specification, chapter 17, section 17.5.4 "Write-protected Fields":

> Normally, a field that is final and static may not be modified.
>   However, System.in, System.out, and System.err are static final fields
>   that, for legacy reasons, must be allowed to be changed by the methods
>   System.setIn, System.setOut, and System.setErr. We refer to these
>   fields as being write-protected to distinguish them from ordinary
>   final fields.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4

Answer (score 10):

I also integrated it with [joor library](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR)

Just use

```
      Reflect.on(yourObject).set("finalFieldName", finalFieldValue);
```

Also I fixed an issue with `override` which the previous solutions seem to miss.
However use this very carefully, only when there's no other good solution.

Comment: When I try this (JDK12), I get an exception: "Can not set final ___ field".

Comment: @AaronIba It's no longer allowed in Java 12+.

Answer (score 8):

Along with top ranked answer you may use a bit simpliest approach. Apache commons `FieldUtils` class already has particular method that can do the stuff. Please, take a look at `FieldUtils.removeFinalModifier` method. You should specify target field instance and accessibility forcing flag (if you play with non-public fields). More info you can find [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html).

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than the currently accepted answer

Comment: Is it? Copying one method sounds like a simpler solution than importing an entire library (which is doing the same thing as the method you'd be copying).

Comment: Does not work in Java 12+: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: In java 12+ final cannot be removed.`

Answer (score 7):

Even in spite of being `final` a field can be modified outside of static initializer and (at least JVM HotSpot) will execute the bytecode perfectly fine.

The problem is that Java compiler does not allow this, but this can be easily bypassed using `objectweb.asm`. Here is p̶e̶r̶f̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶f̶i̶l̶e̶ *an invalid classfile from the JVMS specification standpoint*, but it passes bytecode verification and then is successfully loaded and initialized under JVM HotSpot OpenJDK12:

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_8, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "Cl", null, "java/lang/Object", null);
{
    FieldVisitor fv = cw.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC | Opcodes.ACC_FINAL, "fld", "I", null, null);
    fv.visitEnd();
}
{
    // public void setFinalField1() { //... }
    MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "setFinalField1", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_5);
    mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, "Cl", "fld", "I");
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
    mv.visitEnd();
}
{
    // public void setFinalField2() { //... }
    MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "setFinalField2", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_2);
    mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, "Cl", "fld", "I");
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
    mv.visitEnd();
}
cw.visitEnd();
```

In Java, the class looks roughly speaking as follows:

```
public class Cl{
    private static final int fld;

    public static void setFinalField1(){
        fld = 5;
    }

    public static void setFinalField2(){
        fld = 2;
    }
}
```

which cannot be compiled with `javac`, but can be loaded and executed by JVM.

JVM HotSpot has special treatment of such classes in the sense that it prevents such "constants" from participating in constant folding. This check is done on the [bytecode rewriting phase of class initialization](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/interpreter/rewriter.cpp#l435):

```
// Check if any final field of the class given as parameter is modified
// outside of initializer methods of the class. Fields that are modified
// are marked with a flag. For marked fields, the compilers do not perform
// constant folding (as the field can be changed after initialization).
//
// The check is performed after verification and only if verification has
// succeeded. Therefore, the class is guaranteed to be well-formed.
InstanceKlass* klass = method->method_holder();
u2 bc_index = Bytes::get_Java_u2(bcp + prefix_length + 1);
constantPoolHandle cp(method->constants());
Symbol* ref_class_name = cp->klass_name_at(cp->klass_ref_index_at(bc_index));
if (klass->name() == ref_class_name) {
   Symbol* field_name = cp->name_ref_at(bc_index);
   Symbol* field_sig = cp->signature_ref_at(bc_index);

   fieldDescriptor fd;
   if (klass->find_field(field_name, field_sig, &fd) != NULL) {
      if (fd.access_flags().is_final()) {
         if (fd.access_flags().is_static()) {
            if (!method->is_static_initializer()) {
               fd.set_has_initialized_final_update(true);
            }
          } else {
            if (!method->is_object_initializer()) {
              fd.set_has_initialized_final_update(true);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The only restriction that JVM HotSpot checks is that the `final` field should not be modified outside of the class that the `final` field is declared at.

Comment: this is just pure `EVIL` and beautiful.

Comment: I don’t agree with the “perfectly valid classfile”. The [JVMS §6.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.putstatic) clearly says: “Otherwise, if the resolved field is final, it must be declared in the current class or interface, **and the instruction must occur in the class or interface initialization method** of the current class or interface. Otherwise, an IllegalAccessError is thrown”. So this is just another case where the implementation blatantly violates the specification and has code spread over multiple places to handle what should have been rejected

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the note. I made a correction according to your note to not confuse further readers.

Answer (score 6):

In case of presence of a Security Manager, one can make use of `AccessController.doPrivileged`

Taking the same example from accepted answer above:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class EverythingIsTrue {
    static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");

        // wrapping setAccessible 
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                return null;
            }
        });

        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {      
      setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getField("FALSE"), true);
      System.out.format("Everything is %s", false); // "Everything is true"
    }
}
```

In lambda expression, `AccessController.doPrivileged`, can be simplified to:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction) () -> {
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    return null;
});
```

Comment: yes @dan1st, you are right! Please check this for a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043252/2546381

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 12 onwards, the answers given will not work.

Here is an example on how to modify a `private static final` field since *Java 12* (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039341/get-declared-fields-of-java-lang-reflect-fields-in-jdk12/56043252#56043252)).

```
  private Object modifyField(Object newFieldValue, String fieldName, Object classInstance) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = classInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    VarHandle MODIFIERS;

    field.setAccessible(true);

    var lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
    MODIFIERS = lookup.findVarHandle(Field.class, "modifiers", int.class);
    int mods = field.getModifiers();

    if (Modifier.isFinal(mods)) {
      MODIFIERS.set(field, mods & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    }

    Object previousValue = field.get(classInstance);
    field.set(null, newFieldValue);

    return previousValue;
  }
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039341/get-declared-fields-of-java-lang-reflect-fields-in-jdk12/56043252#56043252) for more details.

Comment: This does not work with Java 16+.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn works if you add `--illegal-access=permit`

Comment: `--illegal-access=permit` was removed in Java 17.

Comment: There is no way to make this work with Java 18 due to [JEP 416](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/416)

Comment: Even in Java 18, [JLS 17.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3) still says "final fields can be changed via reflection and other implementation-dependent means". So what is the reflection mechanism to satisfy the JLS?

Comment: I managed to use `lookup.findSetter(Field.class, "modifiers", int.class)` successfully on both Java 16 and Java 17. However, it still fails on Java 18 because `Field.modifiers` has suddenly become a `final` field.

Comment: @ChrisRankin The mechanism for non-static `final` fields is reflection with `setAccessible`.

Comment: OK, and what is the mechanism for `static final` fields? Because that's the case I'm actually interested in. Specifically - non-primitive `static final` fields, i.e. object references.

Comment: You can't change `static final` fields. [That never really worked](https://gist.github.com/DasBrain/ca16053f8e073c8a883bee66302c2fee). It may appear to work, but in the end - relying on that effect makes your code just non-portable.

Answer (score 4):

With JDK 18 this won't be possible anymore due to the reimplementation of the core reflection over `invokedynamic` and `MethodHandle`s as part of [JEP-416](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/416) ([PR](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/5027)).

Quote of [Mandy Chung](https://github.com/mlchung) – who is the main author of this incredible work – in the [following comment](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/5027#issuecomment-969672078). Emphasis are mine.

> If the underlying field is final, a `Field` object has write access **if and only if**
>
> - `setAccessible(true)` has succeeded for this `Field` object;
> - the field is non-static; and
> - the field's declaring class is not a hidden class; and
> - the field's declaring class is not a record class.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the answers here are useful, but I've found none of them to work on `Android`, in particular. I'm even a pretty hefty user of `Reflect` by *joor*, and neither it nor *apache*'s `FieldUtils` - both mentioned here in some of the answers, do the trick.

### Problem with Android

The fundamental reason why this is so is because on Android there's no `modifiers` field in the `Field` class, which renders any suggestion involving this code (as in the marked answer), useless:

```java
Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

In fact, to quote from `FieldUtils.removeFinalModifier()`:

```java
// Do all JREs implement Field with a private ivar called "modifiers"?
final Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
```

So, the answer is no...

### Solution

Pretty easy - instead of `modifiers`, the field name is `accessFlags`. This does the trick:

```java
Field accessFlagsField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("accessFlags");
accessFlagsField.setAccessible(true);
accessFlagsField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

> Side-note #1: this can work regardless of whether the field is static in the class, or not.

> Side-note #2: Seeing that the field itself could be private, it's recommended to also enable access over the field itself, using `field.setAccessible(true)` (in addition to `accessFlagsField.setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: When running the original code in Android, you will get the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field modifiers in class Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.Field' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)`. The suggested solution works in my case.  (This error currently has only one google result, so hopefully people will now find this page)

Answer (score 2):

Just saw that question on one of the interview question, if possible to change final variable with reflection or in runtime. 
Got really interested, so that what I became with:

```
 /**
 * @author Dmitrijs Lobanovskis
 * @since 03/03/2016.
 */
public class SomeClass {

    private final String str;

    SomeClass(){
        this.str = "This is the string that never changes!";
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Class name: " + getClass() + " Value: " + getStr();
    }
}
```

Some simple class with final String variable. So in the main class 
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

```
/**
 * @author Dmitrijs Lobanovskis
 * @since 03/03/2016.
 */
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        System.out.println(someClass);

        Field field = someClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("str");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        field.set(someClass, "There you are");

        System.out.println(someClass);
    }
}
```

The output will be as follows:

```
Class name: class SomeClass Value: This is the string that never changes!
Class name: class SomeClass Value: There you are

Process finished with exit code 0
```

According to documentation 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable) post?

Comment: This question asks about a `static` final field, so this code doesn't work. `setAccessible(true)` only works for setting final instance fields.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked for me until deployed on JDK 1.8u91.
Then I realized it failed at `field.set(null, newValue);` line when I had read the value via reflection before calling of `setFinalStatic` method.

Probably the read caused somehow different setup of Java reflection internals (namely `sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl` in failing case instead of `sun.reflect.UnsafeStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl` in success case) but I didn't elaborate it further.

Since I needed to temporarily set new value based on old value and later set old value back, I changed signature little bit to provide computation function externally and also return old value:

```
public static <T> T assignFinalField(Object object, Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, UnaryOperator<T> newValueFunction) {
    Field f = null, ff = null;
    try {
        f = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        final int oldM = f.getModifiers();
        final int newM = oldM & ~Modifier.FINAL;
        ff = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        ff.setAccessible(true);
        ff.setInt(f,newM);
        f.setAccessible(true);

        T result = (T)f.get(object);
        T newValue = newValueFunction.apply(result);

        f.set(object,newValue);
        ff.setInt(f,oldM);

        return result;
    } ...
```

However for general case this would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To make this worked with JDK 21 you can use option `-Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false`

Make accessable for JDK 11 - 17

```
    public static void setFieldAccessible(Field field) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Method getDeclaredFields0 = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
    getDeclaredFields0.setAccessible(true);
    Field[] fields = (Field[]) getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field.class, false);
    for (Field each : fields) {
        if ("modifiers".equals(each.getName())) {
            each.setAccessible(true);
            each.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Enjoy while we can on Java 21 because https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8309635 removes it for Java 22

Comment: Code works in Java 21. It's sad that stop works in 22 :( For complete support I need to pass the following VM options `-Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED`

Answer (score 0):

If your field is simply private you can do this:

```
MyClass myClass= new MyClass();
Field aField= myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("someField");
aField.setAccessible(true);
aField.set(myClass, "newValueForAString");
```

and throw/handle NoSuchFieldException

Answer (score -2):

The top rated answer does not work with the new Reflection implementation of [JEP416](https://openjdk.org/jeps/416) in e.g. Java 21 that uses MethodHandles and ignores the flags value on the Field abstraction object.

One solution is to use Unsafe, however with [this JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8323072) Unsafe and the important `long objectFieldOffset(Field f)` and
`long staticFieldOffset(Field f)` methods are getting deprecated for removal so for example this will not work in the future:

```java
final Unsafe unsafe = //..get Unsafe (...and add subsequent --add-opens statements for this to work)
final Field ourField = Example.class.getDeclaredField("changeThis");
final Object staticFieldBase = unsafe.staticFieldBase(ourField);
final long staticFieldOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(ourField);
unsafe.putObject(staticFieldBase, staticFieldOffset, "it works");
```

I do not recommend this but it is possible in Java 21 with the new reflection implementation when making heavy use of the internal API if really needed.

## Java 21+ solution without `Unsafe`

The gist of it is to use a `MethodHandle` that can write to a static final field by getting it from the internal [`getDirectFieldCommon(...)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.java#L4165) method of the Lookup by providing it with a `ReferenceKind` that is manipulated via Reflection to remove the Final flag from it.

```java
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MyClassWithStaticFinalField.class, MethodHandles.lookup());

Method getDirectFieldCommonMethod = lookup.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDirectFieldCommon", byte.class, Class.class, memberNameClass, boolean.class);
        
getDirectFieldCommonMethod.setAccessible(true);
        
//Invoke last method to obtain the method handle
MethodHandle finalFieldHandle = (MethodHandle) getDirectFieldCommonMethod.invoke(lookup, manipulatedReferenceKind, myStaticFinalField.getDeclaringClass(), memberNameInstanceForField, false);
        
finalFieldHandle.invoke("new Value for static final field");
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77705202/23144795) for a full working example on how to leverage the internal API to set a final field in Java 21 without Unsafe.

Comment: You need to quote enough of your other answer to make this answer self-contained. Otherwise this isn’t an answer.

Comment: @user207421 edited to add the quote

Answer (score -5):

The whole point of a `final` field is that it cannot be reassigned once set. The JVM uses this guarentee to maintain consistency in various places (eg inner classes referencing outer variables). So no. Being able to do so would break the JVM!

The solution is not to declare it `final` in the first place.

Comment: Moreover, `final` has a special role in multithreaded execution - changing `final` values would break the Java memory model too.

Comment: And a field not declared `final` should not be declared `static`.

Comment: @Tom: In general that's probably true, but I wouldn't outlaw *all* static mutable variables.

Comment: @bcat It's almost always wrong. You might get away with it for a cache (or you might not).

Comment: @Tom what about a Singleton using a `getInstance()` method that assigns the instance to a static field? You'll also need to reassign a mutable static field when it's a `WeakReference<T>` and the original reference target has disappeared.

Comment: @thecoop It is well known that singletons (a.k.a. globaltons) are evil.

Comment: @Tom: Did you ever read up why singletons are evil? I did! Now I know that they evil only in Java. And only because of the availabilty of a user defined class loader. And ever since I know all this and I don´t use user defined class loader I use singletons without regret. And so does Scala where singleton are a first class language feature
—
That singletons are evil is is a well known **false myth**.

Comment: @Tom: I have 20 years of experience in Software development. I learned a dozen and more programming languages. **I researched the details about Singletons in Java**. So what make you think your are right?

Comment: The final modifier is not intended to protect a field from change. It just indicates, that the programmer of the class doesn't recommend changing this field. Same with accessors. They are only intended to show a user of a class what methods/fields are safe to use.

Comment: @Vincent, isn't it contradict to the [@Péter Török's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection#comment3420182_3301664)?

Comment: @Martin I know that your comment is old, and perhaps your views have changed by now, but I thought I'd just add this: Singletons are evil for reasons that have nothing to do with Java. They add ***hidden complexity*** to your code. Additionally, they can make it impossible to unit test without also knowing that *n* singletons must also be configured first. They are the antithesis of dependency injection. Your team might make the decision that the pitfalls of having *hidden complexity* don't outweigh the convenience of Singletons, but many teams take the opposite stance for good reason.

Comment: No, it does not break the JVM. JVM allows `static final` fields to be modified by methods of the same class.